# Graphing Polynomial Functions with Complex Zeros

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions

I'm in college precalculus and I am curious. I am given a polynomial function $f(x) = x^4 -7x^3 + 18x^2 -22x + 12$ and given that $(1-i)$ is a zero.

I understand that to find the real zeros (factors, solutions, roots) you synthetically divide the polynomial by $(1-i)$, and then divide that quotient by $(1+i)$ which yields a polynomial factorable to obtain real roots. Then I multiplied $(x-(1-i))$ by $(x-(1+i))$ to obtain another polynomial with real roots $(x^2-2x+2)$.

All in all, the original function in factored form is $f(x)=(x^2-2x+2)(x-2)(x-3)$ which seems to match the graph of the given function.

So, my question is... what is the relevance of the problem's given root $(1-i)$? If it doesn't appear on the x,y coordinate plane as a zero, what the heck does it mean? Why is it important and how would you even find this complex root, if say all you were given was $f(x) = x^4 -7x^3 + 18x^2 -22x + 12$ (without being told in the setup that $(1-i)$ was a root)?

I know I can find the fully factored form of the original function with methods not involving this given complex root, so I mean, what's the point? Again, I'm only in precalculus, but I'm assuming they are having us work on these things for a reason (but that reason is not provided in my text).

Comment: Wikipedia [quartic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) provides a way to find the root of degree $4$ polynomials.

Comment: You may want to check out the first pages of the book Visual Complex Analysis. The answer to your question is there :)

Comment: "If it doesn't appear on the x,y coordinate plane as a zero."  This is because the $x,y$ coord. plane necessarily has a domain of $\Bbb{R}$, rather than $\Bbb{C}$, which analogizes to $\Bbb{R^2}.$  Unfortunately, since the domain is two dimensional and the range is (at least potentially) two dimensional, the only way to visualize this is in $3$ dimensions.  Imagine a domain of $\Bbb{C}$ AKA $\Bbb{R^2}$ and a range of $\Bbb{R^2}.$  Instead of visualizing mapping from the $x$-axis to the $y$-axis, you have to visualize a map'g from the domain's plane $\Bbb{R^2}$ to the range's plane $\Bbb{R^2}.$

Comment: "*what is the relevance of the problem's given root $(1−i)$?*" $\,$ It gives you a shortcut to factor the quartic. The polynomial has real coefficients, so if $1-i$ is a root, then so must be its conjugate $1+i$, so it must have a factor of $(x-(1-i))(x-(1+i))$ $=x^2 - 2x +2$. You divide by that factor, and you find the quotient, which is a quadratic easy to factor. This quartic in particular happens to have two integer roots, so you could have factored it using the rational root theorem, even without the $1-i$ hint.